# How to log in Neo4j (respecting original letter case, e.g. uppercase) from Neo4j desktop

Tags: logging, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-desktop

I'm using Neo4j desktop, and trying to use APOC to log a message to the info log.

I've read the documentation on this operation here:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/operational/log/

This is the simple code I'm using, which tries to log "hello world" in both upper and lower case:

```
CALL apoc.log.info('HELLO world')
```

Then I looked here to see where I'd find the log file: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

I'm on a Mac, so I've gone to the logs directory:

```
cd /Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-.../installation-4.0.3/log
```

and ran `tail -f debug.log`:
[image: log file showing "hello_world" (all lower case)]

As you see, the logged message has been converted to lowercase.

In the API docs, I see that there's a property `apoc.user.log.type` which default to `safe` (to "replace all . and whitespace (space and tab) with underscore and lowercase all characters"). I believe I need to set the property value to `raw`, but I'm not sure how.

I've tried these three things with no luck:

```
CALL apoc.log.info('HeLLo', [type: "raw"])
CALL apoc.log.info('HeLLo', { type: "raw" })
:param "apoc.user.log.type" => "raw"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

From the `logs/` directory, navigate to the configuration directory for Neo4j:

```
> cd ../conf
> ls
  jmx.access         jmx.password       neo4j.conf
```

Then add a APOC config file with the `apoc.user.log.type` setting from the APOC docs:

```
> echo "apoc.user.log.type=raw" >> apoc.conf
```

Then restart the Neo4j database / project.

In other words, the configuration that is documented at the `apoc.log.info` function level is actually a global configuration that needs to be set for APOC/Neo4j in general in the configuration file. The config file format is specified here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/